New Mac, unable to get NFS to work. What am I missing?
On my old Mac mini (Mojave), I would add something like "/foo -rw 192.168.0.99" to /etc/exports, restart nfsd, and then I could connect from that IP to the Mac.
On my new Mac mini (Sequoia), nfsd is there and running, but there's no /etc/exports. I tried creating it and then doing the above, but when I do showmount I get nothing:
matt@mattmini2 ~ % showmount -e
Exports list on localhost:

I'm assuming there's a new method for doing this in Sequoia, but if so my googling is failing me. Can anyone help?

Here’s an example of showmount syntax with possibly some other hints. Can you copy and paste the whole command of showmount and the response? Also, does mounting by command work with or without reserved port?

Those links are about connecting from a Mac to an NFS mount point on another server. This is the other way around: I'm trying to share a folder on my Mac via NFS with another machine.
(Apologies, I don't think I made that very clear!)
The entire command and output is what I put in that post. As far as I can see, the command is doing what it's supposed to be doing. The problem is that (I'm assuming) Sequoia just doesn't use "/etc/exports" anymore, so "showmount" isn't reading it.

(I edited the original post to show the result of 'showmount' exactly as it appears.)

Thanks!  I’ll add a post or comment if I can think of anything else to add.

Have checked /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist for a hint?

@AdrianZaugg "com.apple.nfsd.plist" shows that "/etc/exports" is the correct file for configuring the exports. But otherwise there's nothing interesting there. There's also "com.apple.nfsconf.plist", but it's empty. Plus it looks like that file is for settings concerning mounting NFS shares on the Mac that are hosted elsewhere, rather than hosting NFS shares on the Mac.
